# Paypal Rest API With Credit Cart Payment Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

This is how I create PayPal payment.

```
 var apiContext = GetApiContext(clientId, clientSecret);

 CreditCard creditCard = new CreditCard();
 creditCard.number = "4877274905927862";
 creditCard.type = "visa";
 creditCard.expire_month = 11;
 creditCard.expire_year = 2018;
 creditCard.cvv2 = "874";
 creditCard.first_name = firstName;
 creditCard.last_name = lastName;

 Amount amount = new Amount();
 amount.total = "7.47";
 amount.currency = "USD";

 Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
 transaction.amount = amount;
 transaction.description = "This is the payment transaction description.";

 List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>();
 transactions.Add(transaction);

 FundingInstrument fundingInstrument = new FundingInstrument();
 fundingInstrument.credit_card = creditCard;

 List<FundingInstrument> fundingInstruments = new List<FundingInstrument>();
 fundingInstruments.Add(fundingInstrument);

 Payer payer = new Payer();
 payer.funding_instruments = fundingInstruments;
 payer.payment_method = "credit_card";

 Payment payment = new Payment();
 payment.intent = "sale";
 payment.payer = payer;
 payment.transactions = transactions;

 Payment createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
```

For **payment.execute** I need Payment Id and Payer Id. But payer id getting null 
Can you please tell me, How can I get payer Id? am I missing something?

Comment: Assuming I understood your question, the above is a `credit card` `sale` request, you should already get a result from `Create`. IINM `Execute` is for `paypal` payments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please refer Paypal pro API. I think that is good for you and provide better knowledge for you.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do `payment.Execute(...)` when you pay by credit card.

After you create the payment...

```
Payment createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext);
```

..., just call `createdPayment.id` to get the payment ID.

If want to pay by the paypal method you 
would need to `payment.Create(...)`, then `payment.Execute(...)` (after the buyer has approved the payment via a redirect to PayPal).

**About the Payer ID**

When you pay by the paypal method, you do `payment.Create(...)` and then redirect the buyer to PayPal.  After the buyer approved the payment, PayPal redirects to your url and will give you a `PayerID` in the query string. You will then execute the payment something like this:

```
var execution = new PaymentExecution { payer_id = Request.Params["PayerID"] };
payment.Execute(apiContext, execution);
```

Comment: I got an error int the line Payment createdPayment = payment.Create(apiContext); Error Message is  {"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error occurred.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"440c24d115439"}

Comment: This is usually something going on with 
the PayPal server being down or you configured
something wrong. It shouldn't have anything
to do with the code. PayPal used to have a website you could 
go to, to check the status of the servers. You may want to look into that.
It is a frustrating message, I know. If you
have not already done so, you may want to 
take this opportunity implement your error
handling when you get this type of error message. 
You could display a message like "Our servers
are down right now, try again later."

Comment: first of all I want to say thank you for taking care of this. Actually this was my issue i supplied some "test cards" available in internet (That cards work with some other payment gateway like PayU Money). That is not wrks with Paypal , after some research in the Paypal console I fond Generate Card option in the developer console. I used the generated cars it works fine atleast for me.

Comment: But still I have another doubt , How we will recieve the Enter OTP Page while transacting. I couldn't see any redirection while paying with Credit Card in Paypal. Is I missed anythig?

Comment: @Biju, 
I wrapped my payment create call in a try/catch block.  
If there was an exception, my catch block would redirect it to an exception handler function.  
If there was no exception, I would save the payer id, and redirect to the next page.

Comment: I solved my credit card issue in sandbox mode. But my confusion is another which I explained in my last comment, regrading OTP .